# is it good practice to create multiple threads to handle multiple request?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have a client-server application and my server has to process each client request parallely. So I decided to create threads for each request. Is it a good idea to do like this? Inside thread I will be sending response to client so I am not bothering about closing threads.

```
void MyThreadFunction()
{
    //Process request and send response to client
    //.....
    //.....
    return;
}

int main()
{
    //.....
    //.....

    while(true)
    {
        DWORD   dwThreadId;

        if(!receive(clientid, data)) //API to receive data from client
        break;

        CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThreadFunction, NULL, 0, &dwThreadId);   
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is called multithreaded server, but usually you just catch connections and let threads read and write to clients.

Comment: Creating multiple threads is ok, if not necessary, but creating a thread for each request is bad. Use a thread pool instead. Threads are expensive to create/destroy, and they require a lot of memory since each requires its own stack. Use as many as necessary, but no more.

Comment: You may use `std::thread` since C++11.

Comment: Probably better use the ThreadPool API to avoid the overhead of creating a new thread for every incoming request.

Comment: *"so I am not bothering about closing threads."* you should.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to do like this?

No, that's not a good idea.

Since Windows Vista and Server 2008 you can use the (new) [ThreadPool API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766(v=vs.85).aspx).

Explicitly creating a new thread for each incoming request has a certain overhead and will lower your servers performance.

Comment: Can I use C++ 11 std::thread to create a theradpool instead of OS related API?

Comment: @impulse That won't be that efficient (more portable though). With `std::thread` you'll need to roll a thread pool on your own.

Comment: @impulse Easy to wrap into a [c++ interface](http://www.dorodnic.com/blog/2015/10/17/windows-threadpool/) anyways.